# Maximum of the function $f_n(x) = (1 - (1 - x^2)^n) / x$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, contest-math, maxima-minima

> Consider the following function $f_n$ defined on the interval $(0,1]$:
> $$f_n(x) = \frac{1 - (1 - x^2)^n}{x}$$
> Determine the maximum of this function for any natural number $n$.

I have computed the derivative of this function: $f_n(x)' = \frac{2n x^2(1 - x^2)^{n - 1} + (1 - x^2)^n - 1 }{x^2}$, and from $f_n(x)' = 0$ and by denoting $t := 1 - x^2 \in [0, 1]$, I obtained: $(1 - 2n)t^n + 2nt^{n - 1} -1= 0$.
Now to determine the roots of this polynomial in $t$ I denoted the function $g(t) = (1 - 2n)t^n + 2nt^{n - 1} -1$, and computing the derivative of $g$, we get that $g$ is increasing when $t \in [0, 1 - \frac{1}{2n - 1}]$ and is decreasing when $t \in [1 - \frac{1}{2n - 1}, 1]$. Then $g(0) = -1$, $g(1) = 0$, and $g(1 - \frac{1}{2n - 1}) > 0$. Therefore from this we deduce that the unique maximum $t$ belongs to $[0, 1 - \frac{1}{2n-1}]$, or in other words the unique $x$ that maximizes $f$ lies in $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n - 1}}, 1]$.

But I couldnt go beyond this point and if anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it.

Comment: are you asking for $\sup_n\max f_n(x)$ or an explicit formula for $\max f_n(x)$? I think it is unlikely that the latter has an easy formula.

Comment: Just want to point out that $f_n(x)$ is not defined at 0 ($x$ is in the denominator).

Comment: If you have the extremal value for $g$ you can straightforward obtain the extremal value for $f$ with the change of variables. Then it is only left to compare those values with those at the boundary to obtain the absolute ones.

Comment: @dezdichado I would prefer the second, but I would also be happy with the first one.

Comment: @PStheman thank you, you are right.

Comment: @astro I have computed the extremum points of $g$, but $g$ is the derivative of $f$, so I am not sure what to say about the extremum points of $f$ from this.

Comment: I would apply the binomial expansion to simply first (x =0) is a removable singularity.

Comment: @akech I also tried that, but it didnt help me much after.

Comment: @astro No, not really, I have denoted the derivative of $f$ with $g$: $f'(x) = g(x)$ and then I did a change of variable from $x$ to $1 - t$.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the comment since I realized that the change of variables was not that one. Also, I have computed the derivative myself but looks like it will be harder work than seemed at first sight. The one thing I have also noticed is the removable singularity but honestly looks like harder work. Sorry :( and goog luck

Comment: I highly doubt it's possible to find a closed form for the maximum. See the [exact form given by Wolfram when $n=4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+of+%281-%281-x%5E2%29%5E4%29%2Fx+between+x%3D0+and+1) for example. Further, as $n\to+\infty$ we have $\max f_n\to+\infty$ and $x_{\rm critical}\to0$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I agree, it looks like it would be an ugly formula. I think I would also be happy with some bounds on $f_n$

Comment: @astro Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Well we have $2nx_*^2(1-x_*^2)^{n-1}+(1-x_*^2)^n-1=0$ so $f(x_*)=2nx_*(1-x_*^2)^{n-1}$. Any value $X$ such that $x_*\le X<1$ will guarantee a lower bound for $f(x_*)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will add on to dezdichado's answer to find the exact constant on the rate of growth of the maximum. Let $x = \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}} + O\left(n^{-3/2}\right)$. Since it must be true that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-2n)\left( 1-x^2 \right)^{n} + 2n\left(1-x^2 \right)^{n-1}-1=0$$

$x = \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$ can be plugged into this to get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1-2n)\left( 1-\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2 \right)^{n} + 2n\left(1-\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2 \right)^{n-1}-1=0$$

Equivalently, this is $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( 2c^2\left( 1-\frac{c^2}{n} \right)^{n-1}+\left( 1-\frac{c^2}{n} \right)^{n}-1 \right) = 0$$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n = e^x$, this simplifies to $$(2c^2 +1)e^{-c^2}-1=0$$

$c$ is then the positive solution of $\left(2c^2+1\right)e^{-c^2}=1$. The maximal value is then given by $$\frac{2c}{2c^2+1}\sqrt{n} + O\left(n^{-1/2}\right) \approx 0.638 \sqrt{n} + O\left( n^{-1/2} \right)$$

Here are some numerical results concerning the accuracy of this approximation.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & \text{actual maximum} & \text{approximation} & \text{relative error} \\
 10 & 2.084592  &  2.018079 &    3.1907 \cdot 10^{-2} \\
 100 & 6.401867  &  6.381727 &    3.1459 \cdot 10^{-3} \\
 1000 & 20.18713  &  20.18079 &   3.1416 \cdot 10^{-4} \\
 10000 & 63.81927  &  63.81727 &    3.1411 \cdot 10^{-5} \\
 100000 & 201.8086   &  201.8079 &    3.1411 \cdot 10^{-6} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Your solution has been inspiring for me ! Cheers :-)

Comment: It is amazing ! I pushed the expansion to higher orders and even for small $n<10$, it is almoast exact. We even do not need to use $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n = e^x$

Comment: @sandel you should accept this answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I actually took a page from your book with the table and general approach. It is you that has inspired me!

Comment: Thanks for the nice words. Very interesting problem. Play with my last formula if you have time to waste. Which book are you speaking about ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I meant "took a page from your book" in an idiomatic sense, in that I tried writing an answer in the same format and with the same approach as some of your past ones.

Comment: I did not know the expression. Have a look at my latest results for $2 \leq n \leq 10$. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from @Varun Vejalla's solution
$$(2c^2 +1)e^{-c^2}-1=0\tag 1$$ let $t=2c^2+1$ to make
$$\sqrt e\, e^{-\frac{t}{2}} t-1=0$$ Now let $t=2u$ to make $$2\sqrt e\,u \,e^{-u}-1=0$$ that is to say
$$u \,e^{-u}=\frac 1{2\sqrt e}\implies u=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Back to $c$, the solution of $(1)$ is then
$$c=\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+2 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right)\right)}$$
$$\frac{2c}{2c^2+1}=-\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2} \left(1+2 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2
   \sqrt{e}}\right)\right)}}{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{e}}\right)}\approx 0.638173$$

Now, we can push the expansion to higher orders and get for
$$\frac{\sqrt{n} \left(1-\left(1-\frac{c^2}{n}\right)^n\right)}{c}$$ $$\frac{1-e^{-c^2}}{c}\sqrt n\left(1+\frac{c^4}{2 \left(e^{c^2}-1\right) n}-\frac{c^6 \left(3 c^2-8\right)}{24
   \left(e^{c^2}-1\right) n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$  This would give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \text{approximation} \\
 10 & 2.08428 \\
 100 & 6.40186 \\
 1000 & 20.1871 \\
 10000 & 63.8193 \\
 100000 & 201.809 \\
 1000000 & 638.173
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we consider

$$(1-2n)\left( 1-\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2 \right)^{n} + 2n\left(1-\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2 \right)^{n-1}-1=0$$ and expand it for large values of $n$, we have directly
$$\left((2c^2+1) e^{-c^2} -1\right)-\frac{c^4 \left(2 c^2-3\right) e^{-c^2}}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ then the value of $c$.

Now, replacing $e^{-c^2}$ by $\frac 1 {2c^2+1}$, the simpler result
$$\frac{2 c }{2 c^2+1}\sqrt{n} \left(1+\frac{c^2}{4 n}+\frac{c^4 \left(8-3 c^2\right)}{48 n^2}+\frac{c^6 \left(c^4-8
   c^2+12\right)}{96 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \right)$$ which, for $n=50$ gives $4.54116$ to be compared to the result $4.54118$ from Wolfram Alpha as reported by @dezdichado.

It is interesting to notice that $\frac{2 c }{2 c^2+1}\approx 0.638173$ while $(1-e^{-1}) \approx 0.632121$.

Pushing the expansion to much higher orders such as $O\left(\frac{1}{n^{10}}\right)$, it is possible to correctly estimate the results for small values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution}\\
 2 & 1.08728 & 1.08866 \\
 3 & 1.24187 & 1.24281 \\
 4 & 1.38937 & 1.39000 \\
 5 & 1.52553 & 1.52598 \\
 6 & 1.65166 & 1.65200 \\
 7 & 1.76940 & 1.76967 \\
 8 & 1.88010 & 1.88032\\
 9 & 1.98483 & 1.98502 \\
 10 & 2.08443 & 2.08459
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $f_n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ for large $n$, then the numerator:
$$1 - \left(1-\frac 1n\right)^n\sim1 - e^{-1}$$
and therefore your function is at that value is roughly:
$$f_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\sim\sqrt{n}(1-e^{-1}).$$
This means that the maximum of $f_n(x)$ tends to infinity as $n\to\infty.$

For $n = 50,$ wolfram alpha gives the maximum as $4.54$, while the above expression is about $4.469,$ so the maximum for each given $n$ does not seem far off from the above heuristics.

[Wolfram for $n = 50.$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum%20of%20%281-%281-x%5E2%29%5E50%29%2Fx%20between%20x%3D0%20and%201)